# MySQL now allow data to be imported by phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, django, csv, phpmyadmin

I have just ended up creating Django website and now using phpMyAdmin I am importing large data sets in my mode. However, it appears that there is something wrong with the column values which I am trying to import via phpMyAdmin. I see the following error:

```
#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\x93Desig...' for column 'sku_description' at row 1
```

If it was one or two columns I could've manually fixed it. However, as I mentioned there is tons of data in there. What would be the most practical solution for this problem?

Comment: as far as i remember, you can tell phpmyadmin to do some escaping on the import

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I solved it by changing the encoding in excel.

In Excel 2010, save file as CSV and before clicking save, click on Tools->Web Options->Encoding->Unicode(Utf8) and save it. Now import it into MySQL via phpMyAdmin.